# Making VBA Form specific TextBox accept Numbers only and also "."

Tags: vba, excel

I want to block some specific textboxes has numeric values only and accept ".". However, it blocks almost all my textboxes in my userform. I don't understand why. What I forgot in my code?

```
Private Sub tbxHour_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)

'Making TextBox accept Numbers only

If Not IsNumeric(tbxHour.Value) Then
    MsgBox "only numbers allowed"
    Cancel = True
End If

End Sub

Private Sub tbxHour_KeyPress(ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)


Select Case KeyAscii
    Case 46
        If InStr(1, tbxHour, ".") > 0 Then KeyAscii = 0
    Case 48 To 57
    Case Else
        KeyAscii = 0
End Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you have any handlers for the other textboxes? It's hard to tell how the other boxes could possibly be affected by this code you're showing us...

Answer (score 2):

This one worked for me:

```
Private Sub tbxHour_AfterUpdate()

    'Make sure the item is Numeric or has a "." in it
    If Not IsNumeric(Me.tbxHour.Text) And Not Me.tbxHour.Text = "." Then

        MsgBox "This is illegal!"
        Me.tbxHour.Text = ""

    End If

End Sub
```

Short. Simple. Effective and looks like what you're trying to do anyway.

Comment: `If Not validator.IsValidKeyAscii(keyAscii, tbxHour.Value) Then keyAscii = 0` has the advantage of encapsulating the behavior in its own completely reusable unit, *and* it's even shorter and effective (you *prevent* invalid input instead of popping an annoying MsgBox when it's too late).

Comment: Some people like the annoying MsgBox ;) I know most of the people on the Business Side of my company want their employees to get that message box.

Comment: What I mean is, with proper validation you could very well implement much better (less obnoxious, that don't steal focus) notifications, e.g. a little yellow-ish label with a cute little red "X" icon under the textbox, with a friendly message, that gets dismissed as soon as the input is valid again. Or maybe it's just me hating to pop a `MsgBox` for anything other than a critical error =)

Comment: I didn't that X Icon anywhere in your code. Could you add that to your answer?

Comment: Also, the MsgBox doesn't have to be an "angry" message. There are multiple Icons that can accompany it. Normally I use the `vbCritical` if there's something serious I want the user to heed, otherwise I might use `vbInformation` or something like that.

Comment: Meh.. I don't even know what OP is trying to really do, by handling *both* `KeyPress` and `Exit`. I just felt like sharing that validator class I use all the time, the rest is up to whoever choses to use it. For one, a lot of people use forms' *default instance*, which is a terrible practice; IMO it would have been out of scope to go out of my way to depict how I do dialogs and validation. FWIW I only use `vbExclamation`; `vbCritical` is overkill, and `vbInformation` is supposedly ambiguous (per UX guidelines, can't find a link ATM).

Comment: It's a nifty class, I will admit. Although I love the ding that `vbCritical` gives. And you are correct that `vbInformation` is ambiguous, although I think rightfully so. I wish VBA had all the wonderful different dialogs you could pop up that exist in Java and C#. Hopefully we get that soon

Comment: I doubt VB8 will happen as well, as VBA is already pretty outdated. I've heard rumors about the next Excel backend language being more like C#, which I'm all for. You're in luck, as I'm a C# developer. I'd be happy to drop by

Answer (score 0):

I use this simply `NumKeyValidator` class for that, to simply *prevent* invalid input to be supplied by the user:

```
Option Explicit
Private Const vbKeyDot As Integer = 46

Public Function IsValidKeyAscii(ByVal keyAscii As Integer, ByVal value As String) As Boolean
'returns true if specified keyAscii is a number, or if it's a dot and value doesn't already contain one
    IsValidKeyAscii = (keyAscii = vbKeyDot And InStr(1, value, Chr$(vbKeyDot)) = 0) Or (keyAscii >= vbKey0 And keyAscii <= vbKey9)
End Function
```

You can use it by simply declaring an instance field for it:

```
Private validator As New NumKeyValidator
```

And then you use it in each textbox' `KeyPress` handler, like this:

```
Private Sub tbxHour_KeyPress(ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)
    If Not validator.IsValidKeyAscii(keyAscii, tbxHour.Value) Then keyAscii = 0
End Sub
```

There's no need to handle `Exit` and pop a `MsgBox` then - either the box is empty, or it contains a valid number; you could have an `IsValidForm` property that returns `True` if all required textboxes contain numbers, and false otherwise - and then decide that the form's <kbd>Ok</kbd> button is disabled until the form is valid.

FWIW that validator class is quite thoroughly tested (using [Rubberduck](http://rubberduckvba.com) unit tests [disclaimer: I own that open-source VBE add-in project]):

```
Option Explicit
Option Private Module

'@TestModule
'' uncomment for late-binding:
Private Assert As Object
'' early-binding requires reference to Rubberduck.UnitTesting.tlb:
'Private Assert As New Rubberduck.AssertClass

'@TestMethod
Public Sub DotIsValidForEmptyValue()
    On Error GoTo TestFail

    'Arrange:
    Dim actual As Boolean
    Dim sut As New NumKeyValidator

    'Act:
    actual = sut.IsValidKeyAscii(Asc("."), vbNullString)

    'Assert:
    Assert.IsTrue actual

TestExit:
    Exit Sub
TestFail:
    Assert.Fail "Test raised an error: #" & Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
End Sub

'@TestMethod
Public Sub DotIsValidForNonEmptyValueWithoutAnyDots()
    On Error GoTo TestFail

    'Arrange:
    Dim actual As Boolean
    Dim sut As New NumKeyValidator

    'Act:
    actual = sut.IsValidKeyAscii(Asc("."), "123")

    'Assert:
    Assert.IsTrue actual

TestExit:
    Exit Sub
TestFail:
    Assert.Fail "Test raised an error: #" & Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
End Sub

'@TestMethod
Public Sub DotIsInvalidWhenValueHasDot()
    On Error GoTo TestFail

    'Arrange:
    Dim actual As Boolean
    Dim sut As New NumKeyValidator

    'Act:
    actual = sut.IsValidKeyAscii(Asc("."), "123.45")

    'Assert:
    Assert.IsFalse actual

TestExit:
    Exit Sub
TestFail:
    Assert.Fail "Test raised an error: #" & Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
End Sub

'@TestMethod
Public Sub AllDigitsAreValid()
    On Error GoTo TestFail

    Dim sut As New NumKeyValidator

    Assert.IsTrue sut.IsValidKeyAscii(Asc("0"), vbNullString)
    Assert.IsTrue sut.IsValidKeyAscii(Asc("1"), vbNullString)
    Assert.IsTrue sut.IsValidKeyAscii(Asc("2"), vbNullString)
    Assert.IsTrue sut.IsValidKeyAscii(Asc("3"), vbNullString)
    Assert.IsTrue sut.IsValidKeyAscii(Asc("4"), vbNullString)
    Assert.IsTrue sut.IsValidKeyAscii(Asc("5"), vbNullString)
    Assert.IsTrue sut.IsValidKeyAscii(Asc("6"), vbNullString)
    Assert.IsTrue sut.IsValidKeyAscii(Asc("7"), vbNullString)
    Assert.IsTrue sut.IsValidKeyAscii(Asc("8"), vbNullString)
    Assert.IsTrue sut.IsValidKeyAscii(Asc("9"), vbNullString)

TestExit:
    Exit Sub
TestFail:
    Assert.Fail "Test raised an error: #" & Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
End Sub

'@TestMethod
Public Sub AlphaIsInvalid()
    On Error GoTo TestFail

    'Arrange:
    Dim actual As Boolean
    Dim sut As New NumKeyValidator

    'Act:
    actual = sut.IsValidKeyAscii(Asc("a"), vbNullString)

    'Assert:
    Assert.IsFalse actual

TestExit:
    Exit Sub
TestFail:
    Assert.Fail "Test raised an error: #" & Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
End Sub

'@TestMethod
Public Sub DollarSignIsInvalid()
    On Error GoTo TestFail

    'Arrange:
    Dim actual As Boolean
    Dim sut As New NumKeyValidator

    'Act:
    actual = sut.IsValidKeyAscii(Asc("$"), vbNullString)

    'Assert:
    Assert.IsFalse actual

TestExit:
    Exit Sub
TestFail:
    Assert.Fail "Test raised an error: #" & Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
End Sub

'@TestMethod
Public Sub NegativeSignIsInvalid()
    On Error GoTo TestFail

    'Arrange:
    Dim actual As Boolean
    Dim sut As New NumKeyValidator

    'Act:
    actual = sut.IsValidKeyAscii(Asc("-"), vbNullString)

    'Assert:
    Assert.IsFalse actual

TestExit:
    Exit Sub
TestFail:
    Assert.Fail "Test raised an error: #" & Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
End Sub
```

That said I don't see how the code you've shown could ever "block almost all textboxes in your userform".